# How do I get my fortran output into excel?

Tags: excel, fortran

After running a model in fortran (95) I end up with some result arrays (and one result matrix).  I'd like to move these into excel for reporting purposes.  What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As S. Lott said before me, CSV format is probably the best choice, but actually Excel is pretty clever about file formats. It will usually work with tab separated or space separated data, or even HTML tables. Try copy-and-pasting your data into Excel to see whether it can work it out, before worrying too much about the format.

Answer (score 2):

Fix your Fortran output to be in [CSV format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).  This is easily imported into a spreadsheet.

Comment: Much better answer than: fortran_model | sed 's/ /,/g' | excel  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can also write your data into a text file with the below code and then copy paste its contents to excel
before working with these data you must run "paste special wizard" to separate columns of the data in the excel

```
dimension a(100)
open (25,'output.txt')
do i=1,100
write(25,*) a(i)
end do
```