# Export results to Excel for every loop

Tags: excel, process, fortran

I have Fortran code, which calculates the capacity (of a slab) by an incremental applied deflection. In every loop, I apply higher deflection, and I calculate the corresponding capacity. I need to export the results of each loop in order to plot it. I tried to export to a txt file (WRITE command), but every loop replaces the next. So I have the results only of the last loop.

The code is a bit complicated and big. But if it helps, I can upload it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to edit your question and show some source code?

Comment: See [this StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622790/how-do-i-get-my-fortran-output-into-excel) for guidance.

Comment: You don't need to post everything: just the open, write and close parts of your program and roughly where they sit in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to create a character variable that changes with each loop (so that it would be `loop001` for the first iteration, `loop002` for the second, and so on down the line).

You could alternatively use `access=append` in the open statement. With this alternative, I would recommend adding an extra space and a line that tells you what that section of data represents (like, "deflection versus angle 0.17 radians").